# React Native Navigation with Redux: react-navigation-redux-helpers - 'undefined is not an object (evaluation state.routes)'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to implement redux and navigation within a react native application, so I'm trying to follow the instructions for react-native-redux-helpers ([here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-redux-helpers)).

However, I receive the following error upon attempting to start the application:

[image: Error]

**App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './src/reducers/index';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { reduxifyNavigator, createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware, createNavigationReducer } from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';

import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';
import NotesScreen from './src/screens/NotesScreen';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
        screen: LoginScreen
  },
  Notes: {
        screen: NotesScreen
  }
})

const navReducer = createNavigationReducer(AppNavigator);

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  rootReducer,
  navReducer
})

const middleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware('Login', state => state.nav);

const App = reduxifyNavigator(AppNavigator, 'Login');

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  state: state.nav
})

const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

const store = createStore(appReducer, applyMiddleware(middleware));

export default class Root extends React.Component {
  render() {
        return (
              <Provider store={store}>
                    <AppWithNavigationState />
              </Provider>
        )
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am facing the same error, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement your code as stated in the documentation even including the names. It really should work, and in your case is the following:

```
    //delete
import { reduxifyNavigator, ...} from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';
//add 
import { createReduxContainer } from 'react-navigation-redux-helpers';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
          screen: LoginScreen
    },
    Notes: {
          screen: NotesScreen
    }
  })

  const navReducer = createNavigationReducer(AppNavigator);

  const appReducer = combineReducers({
    rootReducer,
    nav : navReducer
  })

  const middleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(state => state.nav);

  const App = createReduxContainer(AppNavigator);

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    state: state.nav
  })

  const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

  const store = createStore(appReducer, applyMiddleware(middleware));

  export default class Root extends React.Component {
    render() {
          return (
                <Provider store={store}>
                      <AppWithNavigationState />
                </Provider>
          )
    }
  }
```